# Remove stopwords using Gensim

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, nlp

I have got this example code.

```
from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import remove_stopwords

text = "Nick likes to play football, however he is not too fond of tennis."
filtered_sentence = remove_stopwords(text)

print(filtered_sentence)
```

However, I'm not familiar with pandas and loop. Say, I have

```
data = {'Text':['I like it.', 'He is happy.', 'This is apple.', 'It is great.']}
df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
```

How can I use loop (I guess it is loop) to remove stop words in `Text` with Gensim `remove_stopwords` and put the results in `data['text_without_stopwords']`? Thanks!

Comment: try `data['text_without_stopwords']=df['Text'].map(remove_stopwords)`

Comment: `df['text_without_stopwords'] = df['Text'].apply(remove_stopwords)` or any of the many options listed in the linked duplicate.